# Angular Rxjs operator that help us start emitting when some variable changes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, operators

I just want to know if is there some rxjs operator that can delay my observable to start emitting when my variable is set to true.

Something like this on Angular:

```js
loading: boolean;

constructor () {
  this.subscriptions.push(
      this._messageService.loadMyEvent$.pipe(
          // here the operator that emitts data when loading is set to true
      ).subscribe(response => {
          // load data
          this.loadData();
          this.loading = false;
      })
  );
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.loading = true;
}
```

So with all of this I want to loadData() when loading is set to true, this means all my content is rendered (AfterViewInit). Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just subscribe in `ngAfterViewInit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a multicast observable like `ReplaySubject` instead of a boolean primitive to emit the values. It could then be combined with the source observable using RxJS `combineLatest` function. It'll emit when any of it's source emits. But note all sources must've emitted at least once for the `combineLatest` to start emitting. You could also use `filter` operator to go forward only when `loading` is true.

Try the following

Controller

```js
loading: ReplaySubject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);

constructor () {
  this.subscriptions.push(
    combineLatest(
      this._messageService.loadMyEvent$,
      this.loading
    ).pipe(
      filter(([response, loading]) => loading)   // <-- emit only when `loading` is true
    ).subscribe({
      next: ([response, loading]) => {
        // load data
        this.loadData();
        this.loading = false;
      },
      error: error => {
        // handle error
      }
    })
  );
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.loading.next(true);       // <-- push `true`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what exactly you want to do but you can merge `EMPTY`:

```
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';

...

this._messageService.loadMyEvent$.pipe(
    switchMap(loading => loading ? someObservable : EMPTY),
).subscribe(response => {
    // load data
    this.loadData();
    this.loading = false;
});
```

Comment: this is a good solution also, I used @Michael D solution